# Android : drawing on activity with other views

Tags: android

I am new to android and trying to make something like the fingerlock security system of the android. The problem is that I have found a lot of reference on drawing onto a plain background (that sets different content view and allows drawing onto that), but not regarding drawing onto the same activity layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *draw* manually on a `View`, you need to override its `onDraw` method. For this you need a custom View (often extending from an existing View type).
If you are using an xml to set the Activity's layout in `setContentView()` then you need to add the above custom view to this xml. Then, you can draw onto the same activity layout.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView is noting but the activity view. once the view is set in main activity (max in oncreate method) it can update from multiple classes according to your logics.. i think before trying this you have to understand the view and its hierarchic properties properly